# AngularJs inject html element in shell from child view from markup

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to angular and have been struggling to work out the best angular approach to solving this problem.

I have my shell page which has a place where I would like an element (toolbar) injected for each view.

Each view can have a slightly different toolbar (heading, buttons etc)

I would like to declare this toolbar in markup in the view so that I can bind data to it that the view is already using, and it's easier to maintain.

My understanding is that I could use a view for the injecting, but all the examples I have seen show it being populated from a template referenced in the routing file.

I have seen a directive used for updating the page title which does similar to what I want, https://github.com/apparentlymart/angularjs-viewhead but when I replicated/altered it and tried injecting complex html markup it didn't like it.

What is the recommended angular approach to solving this problem? Am I approaching the problem the wrong way?

Here is a simplified example.
http://plnkr.co/edit/n23vcBAc4tZUqBxnxcaY?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="example">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
    <a ui-sref="view1" class="md-button" >View 1</a>
        <a ui-sref="view2" class="md-button" >View 2</a>

    <div class="page-contents">
        <div class="toolbar">This should be replaced with the toolbar from each page</div>

        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div data-ui-view="page"></div>
        </div>      
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<div class="view1" style="background-color: yellow;">
    <div class="toolbar-1" style="background-color: gray;">Toolbar 1</div>
    <h2>View 1</h2>
    <div>View contents</div>
</div>

<div class="view2" style="background-color: lightgreen;">
    <div class="toolbar-2" style="background-color: gray;">Toolbar 2</div>
    <h2>View 2</h2>
    <div>View contents</div>
</div>


angular
    .module('example', [
        'ui.router'
    ]);

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('example')
        .config(configureRoutes);

    configureRoutes.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function configureRoutes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('view1', {
                url: '/view1',
                views: {
                    'page': {
                        templateUrl: 'view1.html',
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('view2', {
                url: '/view2',
                views: {
                    'page': {
                        templateUrl: 'view2.html'
                    }
                }
            })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/view1');

    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i solved this was to create a toolbar service and had it populated from the controller. It didn't achieve my original goal of putting it in markup, but it did simplify the implementation.